# Log in with twitter4j

Tags: android, twitter, twitter-oauth, twitter4j

I try to realize an application that log in in Twitter. I utilize the twitter4j like API.
I follow this example:

http://consultingblogs.emc.com/nileeshabojjawar/archive/2010/03/18/twitter4j-oauth-generating-the-access-token.aspx

If you read the example, the application go in a page where is a PIN, but after the user must write the PIN. I would that this step is automatic.
Anyone can suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you're using an outdated tutorial. The tutorial you reference was published in 2010, a lot of things have changed since then. Applications can now be authenticated through a more automatic process.

Check out twitter4j's advice for [application-only authentication](http://blog.twitter4j.org/2013/06/13/59). I'm not sure exactly what your application will be doing, but this seems to be the best option for most people. For more information on application-only authentication itself, check out Twitter's [official documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/application-only-auth).

Alternatively, you can do a traditional OAuth authentication. In that case, there are many more options for ways to authenticate the user. [Here](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/obtaining-access-tokens) is a listing of those options.